# How to change connection pool of MyBatis?

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-cdi

I would like to use a custom connection pool with MyBatis and the following questions have arisen:

What connection pool implementation does MyBatis use?
How can I change the default connection pool by HikariCP or BoneCP?

Answer (score 0):

you can use org.mybatis.spring

```
 @Bean
public SqlSessionFactoryBean mysqlSessionFactoryBean(@Autowired @Qualifier("mysqlDataSource") DataSource source) throws IOException {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    bean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("/mybatis-config.xml"));
    bean.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:/mysqlmapper/**/*Mapper.xml"));
    bean.setDataSource(source);
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
            .url(mysqlUrl)
            .username(mysqlUser)
            .password(mysqlPassword)
            .type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use hikaricp connection pool, set 
sql.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
as sql datasource driver in application.properties